# Regular expression to select substrings in one expression

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
bla bla XX_XXX = 999 OR XX _ XXX = 890 OR XX _X XX = 789 OR XX_ XX = 123
```

and I want to retrieve `XX_XXX` **and** `XX _ XXX` **and** `XX _X XX` **and** `XX_ XX`

I can make each seperately work, but not all at once in one regular expression. Is this possible? How?

Comment: is `_` ALWAYS present in all of those "variable" names? e.g. `/(.{2,3}\s?_\s?.{2,3}) =/` would probably do the trick.

Comment: could you describe your rule, instead of listing examples? Because the way you've asked your question `(XX_XXX)|(XX _ XXX)|(XX _X XX)|(XX_ XX)` would be a correct answer. Something like '2 letters followed by an underscore and three letters - all can be separated by a single space' would be much more meaningful.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear: the x's stand for any alphabetic character so each X can be [a-zA-Z]. the patterns i used were like: "\s[A-Z][A-Z]_ [A-Z]* ="

Comment: Should it expect multiple underscore? Like `XX _XX_ X`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/[A-Z]+\s*_(?:\s*[A-Z])+/
```

The above pattern will match `X`s followed by one or more of

- spaces/underscores followed by `X`s.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dS8gG2/5)

Comment: Sorry to be unclear: the x's stand for any alphabetic character so each X can be [a-zA-Z]. the patterns i used were like: "\s[A-Z][A-Z]_ [A-Z]* ="

Comment: @user782388 did you want to match the leading space?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
(?<=\s|^)[A-Z][A-Z]\s*_(?:\s*[A-Z])+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dS8gG2/3)

**Explanation:**

```
                         '  '
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
 |                        OR
  ^                        the beginning of the string
)                        end of look-behind
[A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
[A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
_                        '_'
(?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                         times):
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                           or more times)
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
)+                       end of grouping
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thanks I will study your answers and learn from it.

Comment: @user782388 Because you're new to Stack overflow, i suggest you to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
([A-Z]\s?){2}_(\s?[A-Z]){2,3}
```

Using your notation, this matches `XX_XX` and `XX_XXX` with an optional whitespace character between any two characters.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tY2mK7/1)